# other Ajax scripts hang when using wordpress jetpack infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

WordPress exchange brought me here:

Using Wordpress 3.6.1, latest Jetpack and latest jQuery as well

My website uses ajax to update post reviews and inline comments on pages of posts(archive, front page, etc) Infinite Scroll works, but when it loads the next page, the js for the newly loaded posts does not work. So the first page works, ajax loaded pages js scripts dont seem to be running. Getting no error messages.

I am thinking it has to do something with the objects loaded not being added to the DOM, but I am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue.

Any ideas? I'd like to avoid editing the ajax plugins and infinite scroll, but adding a hook or something in functions.php that would add the objects to the DOM, at least, if that's the problem. Thanks everyone, looking forward to help on this issue :)

Comment: Yes, that's the problem and you should use delegated event handlers.

Comment: I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this, like I said I'm not getting any error messages so how can I even start?

Comment: The `event handlers` should be delegated, like, `$(document).on('click', '.someElement', function(){...})`.

Comment: You should not touch any plugin's source.

Comment: so I have to use `$(document).on('click')` instead of `$('id_'+id$).click` ????  relaly confused

Comment: Yes, exactly, so, click `event` will fire.

Comment: I'm currently working on one of the plugins, the ajax inline comments plugin: https://github.com/MattMcFarland/inline-ajax-comments > which works great but only on the first loaded page.  Also, using GD Star Ratings, and they ajax load their plugin as well and it doesnt work either on anything but the first page.  Is it something to do with infinite scroll or what?  I'm not sure exactly what to be changing.. Like I said, is there any way I can troubleshoot this, like any cool console trick or anything debug-wise?

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using $(document) ?

Comment: To make delegated event handler, you can bind the event to the parent element.

Comment: Will someone please post an example or a link to a tutorial on this?

Comment: On what, delegated event ?

Comment: https://github.com/MattMcFarland/inline-ajax-comments/blob/master/inc/js/script.js

Comment: Ok I get it, I have to use jquery.on instead, looks like I have to change a bunch of functions, even the GD Star rating functions, when I edit GD Star plugin I'll just use git and make my own version, version control ftw. thanks Sheikh :)

Comment: Would prefer to not use jquery.on though

Answer (score 1):

You have several events, like

```
$('.default-add-comment-form').keypress(function (e){
    //....
});
```

Change all these event handlers ('click' etc) to

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.default-add-comment-form', function (e){
    //...
}
```

So, every events will fire properly even after new content loaded via ajax. Also, for plugins, you may initialize those again, in your `success` callback for new `DOM elements` (if required). Check [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).